# I want to show boxes with certain class in a certain row

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was just trying to show certain div's in certain grid column but it wasn't working. There were empty spaces in the grid. This is the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="div blue"> hi hello</div>
    <div class="div blue"> hi hello</div>
    <div class="div yo"> hi hello</div>
    <div class="div yo"> hi hello</div>
    <div class="div yo"> hi hello</div>
    <div class="div be"> hi hello</div>
    <div class="div be"> hi hello</div>
    <div class="div red"> hi hello</div>
    <div class="div be"> hi hello</div>
    <div class="div red"> hi hello</div>
    <div class="div be"> hi hello</div>
    <div class="div red"> hi hello</div>
    <div class="div blue"> hi hello</div>
    <div class="div yo"> hi hello</div>
    <div class="div yo"> hi hello</div>
    <div class="div yo"> hi hello</div>
    <div class="div be"> hi hello</div>
    <div class="div red"> hi hello</div>
</div>
```

this is the css:

```
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;}
    body{
margin: 50px auto;
width: 80%;
max-width: 1000px; }
    .container{
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;}
    .div{
border: dotted 2px #f4f4f4;
height: 100px;
width: 100%;}
    .yo{
background: yellow;
grid-column: 3/4;}
    .be {
background: rgb(15, 56, 192);
grid-column: 4/5;}
    .red{
background: rgb(212, 16, 16);
grid-column: 1/2;}
    .blue{
background: rgb(0, 238, 255);
grid-column: 2/3;}
```

Now I want to see all the div with class name red in 1st column, blue in 2nd column, yellow in 3rd column and sky blue in 4th column.

It doesn't matter how and where I keep the div with that class in the container div. I want to be able to organize the div's just like I want to.

also, I want the first 5 div's to be independent. that is, I want them to be just as they are. but after those 5 div's I want the rest of the div's to be organized according to as I said, column wise.

I know html, css and learning Javascript Dom. ALL kind of solution is accepted. You can give me a solution using any language(related to web design).

Comment: CSS grid would be perfect for something like this and is probably what you're looking for. There any many great articles on how it works, here's an exhaustive walk through: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ and a quick reference: http://grid.malven.co/ CSS grid isn't the simplest thing, but it's very powerful and probably one the most important parts of CSS to know. Good luck!

Comment: Add `grid-auto-flow: dense;` to your `.container` and then it seems to work like you want, no? https://jsfiddle.net/wb6sr5he/

Comment: So you are not asking about any issue you faced while trying to develop that but asking us to develop it for you?

Comment: Putting the elements in columns is simple but separating the first 5 is not possible with any layout method I am aware of. You may need to rethink.

Answer (score 1):

As @elveti already mentioned, [`grid-auto-flow: dense;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow) is your friend here.

Applying your request for ignoring the first five items, this would be the result:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 1000px;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}


.div {
  border: dotted 2px #f4f4f4;
  grid-column: auto;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}


.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}


.yellow:nth-child(1n+6) {
  grid-column: 3/3;
}

.green:nth-child(1n+6) {
  grid-column: 4/4;
}

.red:nth-child(1n+6) {
  grid-column: 1/1;
}

.blue:nth-child(1n+6) {
  grid-column: 2/2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div blue">hi hello blue</div>
  <div class="div blue">hi hello</div>
  <div class="div yellow">hi hello</div>
  <div class="div yellow">hi hello</div>
  <div class="div yellow">hi hello</div>
  <div class="div green">hi hello</div>
  <div class="div green">hi hello</div>
  <div class="div red">hi hello</div>
  <div class="div green">hi hello</div>
  <div class="div red">hi hello</div>
  <div class="div green">hi hello</div>
  <div class="div red">hi hello</div>
  <div class="div blue">hi hello</div>
  <div class="div yellow">hi hello</div>
  <div class="div yellow">hi hello</div>
  <div class="div yellow">hi hello</div>
  <div class="div green">hi hello</div>
  <div class="div red">hi hello</div>
</div>
```

Note that I changed colors to be more specific since yours are a bit confusing (blue is skyblue).

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH !!!! I have been doing what in my life I don't know But thank you for your solution. I have to go through CSS very very precisely again. Do you have any suggestion on how and where I should learn CSS so that I can also think and find solution to my problems??

Comment: Well, CSS in itself isn't that complicated. It comes down to being efficient at solving layouts in the best way possible, and experience. I'm self-taught all the way and have over 15 years of experience. Just keep on learning. :)

Apart from that, you had a _very_ specific and difficult request and CSS grids are complicated can get over your head times. Don't worry too much about.

Comment: Also, if this answers your question, don't forget to mark it as such. ;) Have a nice day!